# Python CSV Grouped Columns to list of dict of mixed elements

Tags: python, pandas, jython-2.7

I am working on one jython script for websphere which would accept `sys.argv` as `list of dict` to perform further process-

I need help in converting CSV data to list of dictionary mixed of list of tuples as below-

Input CSV-

```
cluster_name,pool_name,min,max,inactive_time,description,action
Clst1,WebContainer,25,25,60000,Revisit,modify
Clst3,WebContainer,50,50,60000,revisit,modify
Clst6,WebContainer,50,50,60000,revisit,modify
Clst1,ORB.thread.pool,,,,,delete
Clst3,ORB.thread.pool,,,,,delete`
```

I am trying to achieve using pandas to group columns but unable to create mixed  element dict

Need below object (list of dict of mixed elements)

```
[
 {cluster_name:'Clst1',
  pool_name:[
         (WebContainer,25,25,60000,Revisit,modify),
         (ORB.thread.pool,,,,,delete)]},
 {cluster_name:'Clst3',
  pool_name:[
         (WebContainer,50,50,60000,revisit,modify), 
         (ORB.thread.pool,,,,,delete)]},
 {cluster_name:'Clst6',
  pool_name:[
         (WebContainer,50,50,60000,revisit,modify)
        ]}
]
```

So that I can use this object as sys.argv to jython script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

csvfile = StringIO("""cluster_name,pool_name,min,max,inactive_time,description,action
Clst1,WebContainer,25,25,60000,Revisit,modify
Clst3,WebContainer,50,50,60000,revisit,modify
Clst6,WebContainer,50,50,60000,revisit,modify
Clst1,ORB.thread.pool,,,,,delete
Clst3,ORB.thread.pool,,,,,delete""")

df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)

s = df.set_index(['cluster_name']).apply(tuple, axis=1).rename('pool_name').groupby(level=0).agg(list).reset_index()

s.to_json(orient='records')
```

Output:

```
[{"cluster_name":"Clst1","pool_name":[["WebContainer",25.0,25.0,60000.0,"Revisit","modify"],["ORB.thread.pool",null,null,null,null,"delete"]]},{"cluster_name":"Clst3","pool_name":[["WebContainer",50.0,50.0,60000.0,"revisit","modify"],["ORB.thread.pool",null,null,null,null,"delete"]]},{"cluster_name":"Clst6","pool_name":[["WebContainer",50.0,50.0,60000.0,"revisit","modify"]]}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Scott for your prompt help :)

Comment: only I used list comprehension for `list` type data `result=[{'cluster_name':row['cluster_name'],'pool_name':row['pool_name']} for index, row in s.iterrows()]`